How do I store time-varying follower-following relationship?
Assume we have a small social media app, containing only 4 people, whos UID = 11, 22, 33, 44 respectively.
These people would follow and unfollow each other over time, and say, I want to take note of their follower relationship on a weekly basis. In other words, I want to store temporal network relationship.
Week 1, their follower network looks like:




primary serial
user own UID
followed UID




1
11
22


2
11
33


3
22
33


4
11
44



Week 2, the change being that user 11 unfollowed 22, and user 44 followed 22:




primary serial
user own UID
followed UID




1
11
33


2
22
33


3
11
44


4
44
22



Finally, now in Week 3, user 11 re-followed user 22:




primary serial
user own UID
followed UID




1
11
22


2
11
33


3
22
33


4
11
44


5
44
22



The 3 tables under each week's network are only for that specific week, but storing these week-tables creates redundancy, since some relations remain unchanged across time:



primary serial
user own UID
followed UID




...
11
33


...
22
33


...
11
44




So I wonder if there is a good way of keeping record of time-varying follower-following relationship across time, in 1 table rather than 3?

And given such a new (less-redundant) table, can I replicate the follower network structure of a given week directly (that is, I can get Week N network without needing to compute from Week 1 to Week N-1 networks)?

Should I add a column of week-specific labels? Should I add a boolean column to indicate whether or not the row's relation still exist?


Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

why not add a timestamp to the table

I would do without the artificial primary key and add a timestamp range that determines when the relationship is valid:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist IN SCHEMA public;

CREATE TABLE follows (
   follower bigint NOT NULL,
   followed bigint NOT NULL,
   valid_range tstzrange NOT NULL,
   EXCLUDE USING gist (
      follower WITH =,
      followed WITH =,
      valid_range WITH &&
   )
);

The exclusion constraint is a replacement for a primary key and will prevent two rows with identical follower and followed and overlapping valid_range.
From PostgreSQL v18 on, you can write that simpler as
CREATE TABLE follows (
   follower bigint NOT NULL,
   followed bigint NOT NULL,
   valid_range tstzrange NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (follower, followed, valid_range WITHOUT OVERLAPS)
);

That is mostly syntactical sugar, but allows you to reference the constraint with a (temporal) foreign key.
To show how it works:
-- user 10 starts following user 20 at 9 a.m.
INSERT INTO follows VALUES
   (10, 20, '[2024-10-10 09:00:00 Europe/Vienna,)');

-- user 10 tries to start following user 20 again at 10 a.m.
-- that fails, because there is already a relationship valid at that time
INSERT INTO follows VALUES
   (10, 20, '[2024-10-10 10:00:00 Europe/Vienna,)');
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "follows_follower_followed_valid_range_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (follower, followed, valid_range)=(10, 20, ["2024-10-10 10:00:00+02",)) conflicts with existing key (follower, followed, valid_range)=(10, 20, ["2024-10-10 09:00:00+02",)).

-- user 10 unfollows user 20 at 10 a.m.
UPDATE follows
   SET valid_range = tstzrange(
                        lower(valid_range),
                        '2024-10-10 10:00:00 Europe/Vienna'
                     )
WHERE follower = 10
  AND followed = 20
  AND valid_range @> TIMESTAMPTZ '2024-10-10 10:00:00 Europe/Vienna';

-- now user 10 can follow user 20 again, starting with 11 a.m.
INSERT INTO follows VALUES
   (10, 20, '[2024-10-10 11:00:00 Europe/Vienna,)');

-- the table contains the complete history
TABLE follows;

 follower │ followed │                     valid_range                     
══════════╪══════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
       10 │       20 │ ["2024-10-10 09:00:00+02","2024-10-10 10:00:00+02")
       10 │       20 │ ["2024-10-10 11:00:00+02",)
(2 rows)

